# How to call an Array of RESTful WebServices from Client?

Tags: java, arrays, web-services, rest

I am very new in RESTful Webservices and Trying to call an array of double[][] values from Client. I can retrieve a single row of Array by using XMLpullparser. I need to call the whole array to client. Please Help. Im gona post the REST webservice codes and client side codes.

REST Webservices-

*(Resource class)*

```
 import java.util.List;

 import javax.jws.WebService;
 import javax.ws.rs.GET;
 import javax.ws.rs.Path;
 import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
 import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

 import org.mushtaq.javabrains.matrix.model.MatrixModel;
 import org.mushtaq.javabrains.matrix.service.MatrixService;


 @Path("/MatrixResource")
 @WebService
 public class MatrixResource {

 double [][] a,b;

    MatrixService ms = new MatrixService();

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public List<MatrixModel> RandomArraynew (){

            a= ms.RandomArray(100);
            b= ms.RandomArray1(100);
            return ms.Multi(a,b);


        }


    }
```

***(Service class)***

```
 package org.mushtaq.javabrains.matrix.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import org.mushtaq.javabrains.matrix.model.MatrixModel;
import org.mushtaq.javabrains.matrix.resource.MatrixResource;

public class MatrixService {

public double[][] RandomArray(int n) {

        double[][] randomMatrix = new double[n][n];
        double[] randomArray = new double[n];
        Random rand = new Random();
        rand.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                Integer r = rand.nextInt() % 100;
                randomMatrix[i][j] = Math.abs(r);
            }
        }

                 return randomMatrix;


    }


    public double[][] RandomArray1(int n) {
        double[][] randomMatrix1 = new double[n][n];
        double[] randomArray = new double[n];
        Random rand = new Random();
        rand.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                Integer r = rand.nextInt() % 100;
                randomMatrix1[i][j] = Math.abs(r);
            }
        }
               return randomMatrix1;

}

    public List<MatrixModel> Multi(double a [][], double b[][]){
        if(a.length == 0) return new double [0][0];
        if(a[0].length != b.length) return null; //invalid dims

        int q = a[0].length;
        int m = a.length;
        int p = b[0].length;

        double ans[][] = new double[m][p];

        for(int i = 0;i < m;i++){
            for(int j = 0;j < p;j++){
                for(int k = 0;k < q;k++){
                    ans[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
                }
            }
        }

          MatrixModel r= new MatrixModel(ans);
          ArrayList<MatrixModel> list = new ArrayList<>();

          list.add(r);
          return list;
    }
}
```

---

### **(Model Class)**

```
 package org.mushtaq.javabrains.matrix.model;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class MatrixModel {

    double [][] result;

    public MatrixModel(){

    }


    public MatrixModel(double [][] result){


        this.result=result;

    }

    public double[][] getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(double[][] result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

 }
```

Above three are the RESTWebservice classes where it should return an array of double[][] values to Client. I can perfectly call it in the browser by the URL= " http://172.21.202.7:8080/matrix/webapi/MatrixResource". It display the Array in XML Format. I am stuck, how to call this whole array from client. As when I call the Service it displays a single row of the Array only.My Client code are given below.

Client Codes-

*(MyActivityClass)*

```
 package com.example.Comp_Offloading;

 import android.app.ActionBar;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
 import android.net.NetworkInfo;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.List;

 public class MyActivity extends Activity {

 TextView txt;
 TextView txt2;
 TextView txt3;
 EditText etxt, etxt2;
 Button bt, bt2;
 TextView output;
 ProgressBar pb;
 ActionBar ab;
 List<Matrix> matlist;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    txt3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    etxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    etxt2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    bt2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    //i = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);



    bt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){

            etxt.setText("");
            etxt2.setText("");
            txt.setText("");
            etxt.requestFocus();
        }
    });


    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (isOnline())   
       {requestData("http://172.21.202.7:8080/matrix/webapi
        /MatrixResource");
            }

        }

    });}


private void requestData(String Uri) {
    MyTask task= new MyTask();
    task.execute(Uri);
}

protected void updateDisplay() {

    if (matlist != null) {
        for (Matrix matrix : matlist) {
            txt.append(matrix.getResult() + "");

        }


    }
}

protected boolean isOnline(){

    ConnectivityManager cm= (ConnectivityManager)
    getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netinfo=cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netinfo != null && netinfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Network is not available", 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;}
 }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        //updateDisplay("Starting Task...");
        //pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String content = null;
        try {
            content = HttpManager.getData(params[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return content;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        matlist = MatrixXMLParser.parseFeed(result);

        updateDisplay();
        //pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }



 }
```

}

***(HTTPManager Class)***

```
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.InputStreamReader;
  import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
  import java.net.URL;

  public class HttpManager {

    public static String getData(String Uri) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(Uri);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    reader= new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

            String line;

            while((line= reader.readLine()) !=null){

                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            return sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }finally {

            if(reader !=null){
                reader.close();
            }
        }
    }
}

***(XMLPullparser Class)***



 package com.example.Comp_Offloading;

 import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
 import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

 import java.io.StringReader;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Arrays;
 import java.util.List;

 public class MatrixXMLParser {

 public static List<Matrix> parseFeed(String content) {

    try {
        boolean inDataItemTag = false;
        String currenTagName = "";
        Matrix matrix = null;

        List<Matrix> matlist = new ArrayList<>();

        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();
        parser.setInput(new StringReader(content));

        int everntType = parser.getEventType();

        while (everntType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            switch (everntType) {

                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:

                    currenTagName = parser.getName();
                    if (currenTagName.equals("result")) {
                        inDataItemTag = true;

                        matrix = new Matrix();
                        matlist.add(matrix);
                    }
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:

                    if (parser.getName().equals("result")) {

                        inDataItemTag = false;
                    }
                    currenTagName = "";

                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:

                    if (inDataItemTag && matrix != null) {
                        switch (currenTagName) {

  case "item":matrix.setResult(Double.parseDouble(parser.getText()));
  break;
                 default:
                 break;
                        }
                    }

                    break;

            }

            everntType = parser.next();
        }

        return matlist;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

 }
}

***(Model Class)***

 package com.example.Comp_Offloading;

 public class Matrix {

 private double item;

 public double getResult() {
    return item;
}

public void setResult(double result) {
    this.item = result;
}
```

}

Please help. Check and suggest whats wrong in the Client side Code. what should I add to call the whole array and display in client. Also suggest, if there is  any other easy way other than XMLpullparser to display the whole array as a plain text. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

HTTP responses do not support Arrays in plain text responses.
You either need to manually represent your array as a String, change the return type to String and return like this:

```
return Arrays.toString(arr);
```

Or you could convert your array to a List: return Arrays.asList(arr);

Comment: I have chnaged the return tryoe to String and when I ran the code in browser I get this error.   " This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error."  .    Please help.

Comment: Put @Produces as @Produces("text/html") instead of xml for return type string.

Comment: Hey Tanvi B.. Its working now. BUt i need to ask about the XMLpullparser. Can I display the whole array from webservice to client without using XMLparser?  May be I am wrong buh untill now I think that if we want to receive anydata from webservice we will need to use XMLparsert for plain text display. Is this right?

Comment: No XML parser is not required

Comment: Then please can you  check my client side codes and suggest how to make a call then, as I am using a seperate class XmlPullParser because i read somewhere that when we we call a webservice from Client, the receiving data is either in the form of XML or Json. If we do not use any Parser then how can the data be in plain format? I am really stuck in it.

Comment: Tanvi B.  Im still waiting. plz give me some idea how to call that service without XMLpullparser. Just to call the webservice to get array of double values. Plz..  Thankx

Comment: I am not sure about without XMLpullparser